# Find the general formula for this Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

[image]

Again stuck on this stuff.

I swear I had the right answer... 4 times in a row... and now I'm stuck with one attempt left and i'm afraid to try again

I think what I am doing wrong, is I am missing the part of the pattern where the numerator is multiplied by -7.

I think my answer should be reflecting that each time, it is being multiplied by -1, -2, -6, -24, but I don't know how to show this in my series.

Comment: Notice that when you are taking the derivatives of $\dfrac{7}{x}$ you are getting a factorial term in the numerator. So that will affect the factorial in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You can simplify the problem setting $x=y+a$. So $$f=\frac 7 x=\frac 7 {y+a}=\frac 7a \frac{1}{1+\frac y a}$$ Now, let $z=\frac y a$ which make $$f=\frac 7a \frac{1}{1+z}$$ Now, remember that $$\frac{1}{1+z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n$$ Go back to $y$ and then to $x$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: How would you go back from y > x?

Comment: @dmscs. $y=a z$ and $x=y +a$